# Flutter bug with nested scrollviews

Tags: flutter, scrollview

In my Flutter App, I have a Screen with a `PageView` that shows Cards. Some of the Cards have `TextFields`, so I put the Screen into a `SingleChildScrollView`, so that the Keyboard pushes the screen to the top and does not overlap. Here is an example of the code:

```
class DummyScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: PageView(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            DummyCard(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, some of the cards have a lot of TextFields and on smaller screens it would be too large. So I also put them into a ScrollView. This means I have a widget that contains a `ScrollView`, inside a `PageView`, inside a `ScrollView`:
(This is not the exact code, the styling parts are missing, obviously)

```
class DummyCard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 14, vertical: 14),
        child: Scrollbar(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "TextField 1"),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "TextField 2"),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "TextField 3"),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "TextField 4"),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "TextField 5"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Dummy Card]
[image: Dummy Card]

The `PageView` should not be scrollable, but should change the page on a button tap. So that is no problem. When The Keyboard is not opened, it is not a problem either, because the outer `ScrollView` is not scrollable, when the keyboard is not opened. The Problem occurs when I tap on a TextField and the Keyboard pops up. Now I have a scrollable `ScrollView` on the outside (the whole screen), and a scrollable `ScrollView` inside the `Card`, which leads to the following two problems:

1. The scrolling behavior is not good in general. When I tap the screen inside the `Card`, I can only scroll the inner `ScrollView`, even if I have already scrolled "to the end". So when I want to scroll the outer `ScrollView`, I have to tap the screen outside of the `Card`, which is not a very nice user experience.
2. When I tap a `TextField`, I want the screen to be pushed to the top. But as the `TextFields` are inside the inner `ScrollView`, it only pushes the inner `ScrollView` to the top, which often leads to the keyboard still overlapping the `TextField`.

I know that it is not a good practice to have 2 `ScrollViews` with the same scroll direction nested in each other. But it is the only solution that came to my mind. I definitely need the `ScrollView` inside the card. And I also want to push the screen to the top when the keyboard pops up, I don't want to shrink the screen (not possible with my layout). So, any ideas on how I can fix the above 2 problems?

Comment: about problem 1 :` NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),` means you cant scroll outter `ScrollView`. can you share prototype/video that you want to archive

Comment: Yeah, the `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` is in the `PageView`, not in the `ScrollView`. Unfortunately, I don't have a prototype, but I can try to explain it a little bit better if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Scaffold has a property which will prevent resizing the page on keyboard open, which is true by default. Try to set it to false

> bool? resizeToAvoidBottomInset

Comment: Already did that. But that doesn't change the behavior of the nested `ScrollViews`

Comment: Could you try to remove SingleChildScrollView before PageView?